# ajax url+current input values required

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a link to ajax.. it works.. now i want to add the current form values to ajax request..

```
$datepicker=$("#datepicker").val();
```

i know that i can use val() to get current values, but i am sending url here, where should i include this as datastring.. Hope am clear..This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.member').click(function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.href,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                      $("#result2").append(data);
            }
     });
     return false;
}); 
});
</script>
<body>

<a href="http://ex.net/free/action.php?me=1"  class="member" id="member" rel="example">click to launch</a>

<br><br<
<form id="form1">

<input type="text" id="name" value="name"><br>
<input type="text" id="name1" value="name1">
</form>
<div id="result2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advances,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:this.href,
  data:"{'val': '" + $("#datepicker").val() + "'}",
  cache:false,
        success: function(data){
                  $("#result2").append(data);
        }
});
```

OR

Try this one.

```
       $.post(this.href,"val="+$("#datepicker").val());
```

Use data in ajax.hope this will work.

To get the value like 
                $_REQUEST['val'].

For further process refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example).

Comment: i tried using request but it doesn't display?? any idea?? i used echo $_REQUEST['val']; but no display @Nirmal

Comment: just check in your browser whether the value is passing or not!!

Answer (score 1):

you should add the '**data**' attribute in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "{'ParameterName': '" + $("#datepicker").val() + "'}",
            url: this.href,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                      $("#result2").append(data);
            }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.member').click(function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {'postedData':$("#form_name").serialize()},  
            url: this.href,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                      $("#result2").append(data);
            }
     });
     return false;
}); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: and how do i retrieve it from my action page?? using postedarray ah